# How to get the Average of a specific category via Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, average

I was wondering how I could calculate the average of a specific category via Python? I have a csv file called demo.csv

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

#loading the data into data frame
X = pd.read_csv('demo.csv')
```

the two columns of interest are the `Category` and `Totals` column:

```
Category Totals estimates
2   2777    0.43
4   1003    0.26
4   3473    0.65
4   2638    0.17
1   2855    0.74
0   2196    0.13
0   2630    0.91
2   2714    0.39
3   2472    0.51
0   1090    0.12
```

I'm interested in finding the average for the Totals corresponding with `Category` 2. I know how to do this on excel, I would just filter to only show category 2 and get the average(which ends up being 2745.5) but how would I code this via Python?

Comment: sum(x[1]) / len(x[1]) ? Would be x[1] a list/tuple or sth like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict your dataframe to the subset of the rows you want(`Category=2`), followed by taking mean of the columns corresponding to `Totals` column as follows:

```
df[df['Category'] == 2]['Totals'].mean()
2745.5
```

Comment: i would use indexer (it looks bit better): `df.ix[df['Category'] == 2, 'Totals'].mean()`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm interested in finding the average for the Totals corresponding with Category 2

You may set the category as the index then calculate the mean for any category using the `.loc` or `.ix` indexers:

```
df.set_index('Category').loc['2', 'Totals'].mean()
=> 2745.50

df.set_index('Category').ix['2', 'Totals'].mean()
=> 2745.50
```

The same can be achieved by using `groupby`

```
df.groupby('Category').Totals.mean().loc['2']
=> 2745.50
```

Note I'm assuming `Category` is a string.